# How to navigate to other Viewcontroller when in parsing Json from URLsession

Tags: ios, swift3

1)I have the following:
- a textField for user to input some data like username
- added an activityIndicator

2)when user hit the Keyboard 'Return ' or 'Go' or 'Done' key, it will call the SendPostRequest func as below code.

The code has no compilation error.

Is there any problem to navigate inside the URLSession?

**problem**:

terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
func textFieldShouldReturn( _ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

 ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
 SendPostRequest()

}


unc SendPostRequest(user: String ) {
        let Url = String(format: "your url")
        guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }

        let parameterDictionary = ["username" : "User1"]
        var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
            return
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                   //condition met:
                   let jsonStatus: String! = json["Status"] as String

                   if jsonStatus == "Code123"

                   self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueAcct",sender: self )


                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. There are (at least) two issues: Swift is case sensitive: `jsonStatus` != `JsonStatus` and the body of an `if` statement must be in braces.

Comment: Also, URLSession runs asynchronously, your closure with strong self capture, may leak.

Comment: Sorry , It is a typo error. I made a change as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the code in the completion block is running on the background thread so just post `performSegue` on the main thread like so

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueAcct",sender: self )
}
```

Comment: If this doesnt work add a print log before performing the segue to make sure you are parsing correctly and that you get to this part of the code...